# How to show Record by input CNIC Number in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, html, regex, laravel

**conroller**

```
public function search()
{
    $search=\Request::get('search');
    $needy=needAuth::where('cnic','like','%'.$search.'%')->orderBy('id')->paginate(30);

    return view('needyStatus', compact('needy'));
}
```

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','url'=>'needyStatus','class'=>'navbar-form navbar-left','role'=>'search'])!!}
  <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default-sm">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
<tr>
  <hidden>
    @foreach($needy as $ned)
    {{$ned->cnic}}
    {{$ned->email}}
    '{{$ned->firstName}}
    @endforeach
  </hidden>
</tr>
```

i enter CNIC it shows but when i refresh page is shows all data without enter any cnic number. how to hide data and only show by enter cnic number which show record?

Answer (score 0):

Give the condition here:

```
public function search(){
     $search=\Request::get('search');
     if(isset($search)){
        $needy=needAuth::where('cnic','like','%'.$search.'%')->orderBy('id')->paginate(30);
     }
    return view('needyStatus', compact('needy'));
}
```

Comment: Not working... undefine variable $needy. but i have declare in controller and when i put braces it shows this error.

Comment: put this line in if condition  return view('needyStatus', compact('needy'));